# How does a "Haskell Resonator" work?

Tags: acoustics, resonance

I would like a simple explanation of how a "[Haskell Resonator](http://www.organstops.org/_apps/HaskellBasses.html)" works. You may assume that I understand the Wikipedia paragraphs on open and closed resonator cylinders.

Exactly how does placement of these cylinders-within-cylinders change the resonant frequencies?

Is a general rule known? [Using *n* nested cylinders, some closed or open]

Should a Haskelled resonator of fundamental frequency *x* and outer diameter *D* be more or less sensitive than a non-Haskelled resonator of fundamental frequency *x* and outer diameter *D*? [My naive guess is "more" because there would be less mass in the Haskelled version, provided it was a smaller tube in a larger one.]

I saw this type of thing used on a marimba ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H0wTEz5VwY#t=7m32s)), and it made me curious as to how and why this works.

Comment: When you ask about a *more sensitive* resonator, do you mean a higher [quality factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance#Q_factor)?